# Can I adjust the Firestore Listener Frequency?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Flutter & Firebase app that provides users with price updates on the dashboard on the main screen. It does this with a Firestore Snapshot Listener, but my read count is flying through the roof (I'm at 203 reads and just 1 device is connected)... This info will only change once a month, and it really doesn't need to keep checking for updates at all times.

Is there a way to setup the listener so that it checks less frequently for updates? Or perhaps, can I setup a Firebase In-App Messaging system with which I send the price out and the app just saves and displays it?

Or is there any efficient solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Since the Listener (which you do not show, so we can't even help you there) **ONLY** triggers when there is an update to the documents (**NOT** on a schedule) *something* is updating the collection you are listening to.  203 is not particularly high over a few days - how long has your app been running?  Have you been restarting the app frequently?  Most Listeners will give you a result **at least once** when you initialize them - i.e. when you start the app.  There is no "long-term global memory" like that.

Answer (score 0):

A listener will always receive updates as soon as they becomes available.  This can't be configured.  If you want a different update frequency, you should instead schedule that yourself within the app, and use `get()` to poll the database as often as you need.  You can also use FCM on your backend to push updates to the app, if that works for your case.